# How to pass a default value to a Spring input/hidden element?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Suppose, I have the following Spring form

```
<form:form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" 
           method="post" action="Temp.htm" commandName="tempBean">

    <form:hidden path="stringValue" />

</form:form>
```

The hidden field is mapped with the command bean - `TempBean`. What if, I need to pass a default value which is dynamic to this hidden field and dependent upon some other operations?

---

HTML context:

```
<c:set var="someVariable" value="${someValue}"/>

<input type="hidden" 
       id="stringValue" 
       name="stringValue" 
       value="${someVariable}"/>
```

The tags like `<form:input>` and `<form:hidden>` don't have a `value` attribute. So, how to pass a default value to a command object in this scenario?

I'm using Spring 3.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value to the bean you are using in common name

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someView.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String someView(ModelMap modelMap){

        TempBean tempBean = new TempBean();
                tempBean.setStringValue(somevalue);
        modelMap.addAttribute(tempBean );
        return "something";
    }
```